# any difference between x=0 and x=0.0 for a double x variable? c code

Tags: c, double

Is there any difference between

```
double x;
x=0;
```

and

```
double x;
x=0.0;
```

might be a stupid question but i can't really find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, there doesn't have to be any difference although there is an implicit conversion in the first case since `0` is an `int`.

I tried it (on [assembly.ynh.io](http://assembly.ynh.io/)). This C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double x, y;

  x = 0;
  y = 0.;

  printf("x=%g and y=%g\n", x, y);

  return 0;
}
```

generated the following assembly for the two assignments (to `x` and `y`):

```
0008 B8000000 00  movl  $0, %eax
000d 488945F0     movq  %rax, -16(%rbp)
0011 B8000000 00  movl  $0, %eax
0016 488945F8     movq  %rax, -8(%rbp)
```

In other words, the code is exactly the same. This was built by GCC, without optimization.

I guess this takes advantage of the fact that the bitpatterns are all zero in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In `x = 0` there is an implicit type promotion performed to convert `0` (which in `int`) to `double` `0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there won't be any difference to your code output if used exactly like that, but with `x=0` the compiler has to perform implicit type conversion of the 0 from an `int` (0) to a `double`(0.0). Worst case, increases your compile time by a few nanoseconds maybe?